# Windows Phone App 8.1 On Click Error

Tags: windows-phone-8, onclick

Hi im trying to make an windows phone app which allows users to be given a random word from a list which is then scrambled , and if they guess what the original word is then get another and also a point. My problem is whenever someone gets one right and you click on the button to make sure it is right there is a number of clicks before you get a new one , i was wondering how you get one click when you get one right and get a new random word.

```
n = list -  strings
```

also if i add , `answer.Text != sum` as another if it seems to always bring it up even when right. i need help

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     Random rnd = new Random();
     int index = rnd.Next(0, n.Count);
     string sum = n[index];

     if (answer.Text == sum)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Correc");

          answer.Text = "";

          numberofscore++;

          playerScore.Text = Convert.ToString(numberofscore);


          rnd = new Random();
          int i = rnd.Next(0, n.Count);
          string s = n[i];

          soap.Text = ScrambleWord(s);

     }

  }


public string ScrambleWord(string word)
{
       char[] chars = new char[word.Length];
       Random rand = new Random(10000);

       int index = 0;

       while (word.Length > 0)
       {
            // Get a random number between 0 and the length of the word.
            int next = rand.Next(0, word.Length - 1);

            // Take the character from the random position and add to our char array.
            chars[index] = word[next];

            // Remove the character from the word.
            word = word.Substring(0, next) + word.Substring(next + 1);

            ++index;
        }

        return new String(chars);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to restrict the call of Button_Click event only when the answer in "answer" textbox is right.
Since "Click" event will always fire when user clicks the button if it is subscribed, only way is to stop it is to unsubscribe the event. Or disable the button.

Try this.

First declare variable sum, and n[] array (your word list array) globally, above constructor of the class. Your code in Button_Click remains same and should work.

Use TextChanged event of your textbox, it will call textBox_TextChanged event whenever text is changed.
Now using answer_TextChanged event, i.e. TextChanged event of your TextBox

```
private void answer_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // button is name of your Button control

             if(answer.Text==sum)
             {
                 // If answer is right, subscribe to event
                 // so it will fire on click
                 button.Click+=Button_Click; 


                 // OR
                 // Write code to ENABLE BUTTON
             }
             else
             {
                 // If answer is wrong, unsubscribe to event
                 // so it will not fire button_Click event
                 button.Click+=Button_Click;



                 // OR
                 // Write code to DISABLE BUTTON
             }

    }
```

Note that you have to declare sum outside the button_Click event so it can be accessible to other methods. Also in constructor, unsubscribe event OR disable button since no answer is expected on initialization of the page/app.